# Availability of #include <map> with xlC on AIX 4.3

Tags: c++, aix, xlc

Is there a version of xlC/VACPP available for AIX 4.3, which does not choke when given following source:

```
#include <map>

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

If yes, is it still available anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using [STLport](http://www.stlport.org/) as a replacement for the STL shipped with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the compiler, per se, but the fact that the compiler shipped with an old version of the STL.  You should be able to install [Apache's STL](http://stdcxx.apache.org/#platforms) to fix this.